# ant 1.9.7 chmod returns 127 on Solaris 10

Tags: ant, solaris-10

I am using ant to deploy a file and then change the permissions of the file, but I am getting a 127 result to the chmod which means that there is an issue with the path or a typo:

```
[chmod] Result: 127
```

I have checked if the path to chmod was in the $PATH I am using and both check:

```
  /program/EU/17_B_30/home/> echo $PATH
/products/maven/bin:/program/installs/java6/bin:/products/maven/bin:/program/installs/java6/bin:/program/EU/17_B_30/home/Jre/bin:/program/EU/17_B_30/home/Scripts:/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/:/program/php/bin/:/usr/ccs/bin/:/usr/sfw/bin/:/opt/sfw/bin/:/program/installs/java6/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
/program/EU/17_B_30/home/> which chmod
/usr/local/bin/chmod
```

The same script executes without error on Linux hosts.

This is the ant task call that I am using:

```
 <chmod file="${filesystem.target}/Scripts/file.sh" perm="ug+x"/>
```

Any questions/suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Try running Ant with the `-verbose` option. This will print the command the `<chmod>` task is trying to use to run the `chmod` executable.

Comment: Why in the world do you have a `/usr/local/bin/chmod`?  Try running your ant command as `truss -f -a -vall -t\!all -texecve -o /path/to/some/output/file ant ...`.  Find the failing `execve` call in all the output and see what arguments are passed to it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was also surprised by the location of the chmod, I was given that server to test a build on Solaris 10... thanks for the suggestion I will try that